# ConnectionError: Error 104 while writing to socket. Connection reset by peer

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, sockets, redis

ConnectionError: Error 104 while writing to socket. Connection reset by peer.

Environment:
ubuntu : 16.04
python : 3.6
PC total memory : 32G

I have redis '3.0.6' installed.

It succeeds when you try to insert 500,000 data, but fails when you try to insert 40 million large data.

When trying to insert Python data frame into redis, it fails because the capacity is too large.

data insert Sucessful:

```
 1. r = redis.StrictRedis(host='localhost', port=6379, db=0)
 2.log_df_50.shape
   -> (500000, 6)
 3.r.setex('log_df_50',100,log_df_50.to_json())
   -> True
```

data insert Fail:

```
 1.r = redis.StrictRedis(host='localhost', port=6379, db=0)
 2. log_df.shape
   -> (41757802, 6)
 3. r.setex('session',100,log_df.to_json())
```

---

> ConnectionResetError    Traceback (most recent call last)
> ~/anaconda3/envs/Colabo/lib/python3.6/site-packages/redis/connection.py
> in send_packed_command(self, command, check_health)
> 705             for item in command:
> --> 706                 sendall(self._sock, item)
> 707         except socket.timeout:
>
> ~/anaconda3/envs/Colabo/lib/python3.6/site-packages/redis/_compat.py
> in sendall(sock, *args, **kwargs)
> 8 def sendall(sock, *args, **kwargs):
> ----> 9     return sock.sendall(*args, **kwargs)
> 10
>
> ConnectionResetError: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> ConnectionError         Traceback (most recent call last)
>  in 
> ----> 1 r.setex('session',100,log_df.to_json())
>
> ~/anaconda3/envs/Colabo/lib/python3.6/site-packages/redis/client.py in
> setex(self, name, time, value)    1820         if isinstance(time,
> datetime.timedelta):    1821             time =
> int(time.total_seconds())
> -> 1822         return self.execute_command('SETEX', name, time, value)    1823     1824     def setnx(self, name, value):
>
> ~/anaconda3/envs/Colabo/lib/python3.6/site-packages/redis/client.py in
> execute_command(self, *args, **options)
> 898         conn = self.connection or pool.get_connection(command_name, **options)
> 899         try:
> --> 900             conn.send_command(*args)
> 901             return self.parse_response(conn, command_name, **options)
> 902         except (ConnectionError, TimeoutError) as e:
>
> ~/anaconda3/envs/Colabo/lib/python3.6/site-packages/redis/connection.py
> in send_command(self, *args, **kwargs)
> 724         "Pack and send a command to the Redis server"
> 725         self.send_packed_command(self.pack_command(*args),
> --> 726                                  check_health=kwargs.get('check_health', True))
> 727
> 728     def can_read(self, timeout=0):
>
> ~/anaconda3/envs/Colabo/lib/python3.6/site-packages/redis/connection.py
> in send_packed_command(self, command, check_health)
> 716                 errmsg = e.args[1]
> 717             raise ConnectionError("Error %s while writing to socket. %s." %
> --> 718                                   (errno, errmsg))
> 719         except BaseException:
> 720             self.disconnect()
>
> ConnectionError: Error 104 while writing to socket. Connection reset
> by peer.

Any hints on the cause?

How do you insert python Large capacity Dataframe into redis?

What should i do to solve this problem?

Answer (score 7):

I think that the problem is with the 512 MB limit for the key/value in Redis' protocol.
https://redis.io/topics/protocol
https://redis.io/topics/data-types-intro

And there is not much you can do about it now.

You probably have to just slice your dataframes into smaller pieces.

UPDATE:
You can also use newer Redis (minimum 5.0) and increase `proto-max-bulk-len` in `redis.conf`.
https://github.com/redis/redis/issues/7354
I also had to increase `client-query-buffer-limit`.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue.
Setting **ssl=True** in

```
1. r = redis.StrictRedis(host='localhost', port=6379, db=0, ssl=True)
```

solved it for me

Comment: When ssl = True, no data is entered and execution is never finished.
how to solve it?

Comment: How to split and insert data little by little?

Comment: Could someone explain to me how enabling encryption can solve data serialization and/or upload timeouts we are apparently dealing with here?

Comment: Since my answer is already two years old, I can add that enabling SSL for the redis instance in fact may not solve any issues regarding data serialization and upload issues and is not the solution to the original problem.